# Kafka Connect : Can any field in avro schema ignore when sink data to database table?

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-schema-registry

I have an requirement that needs a avro schema for multi purpose. Some fields in avro schema does not need to sink in database table. For example :

My avro schema is :

```
{
  "namespace": "com.test.clearing",
  "type": "record",
  "name": "ClearingTest",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "ID",
      "type": "int"
    },
    {
      "name": "ITEM",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
        "name": "STAT",
        "type": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

and my table DDL is:

```
-- auto-generated definition
create table CLEARING_TEST
(
    ID int not null primary key,
    ITEM varchar(200) null
);
```

Can i ignore `STAT` field in kafka connector for sinking in database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Kafka Connect's Single Message Transform (SMT) and more precisely [`replaceField`](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/transforms/replacefield.html) using `blacklist` in order to drop a field so that it is ignored when inserting messages from Kafka to your target database:

```
"transforms": "ReplaceField",
"transforms.ReplaceField.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ReplaceField$Value",
"transforms.ReplaceField.blacklist": "STAT"
```

---

Now the original message:

```
{"ID": 1, "ITEM": "myItem", "STAT": "myStat"}
```

will be transformed to:

```
{"ID": 1, "ITEM": "myItem"}
```

Comment: Do i add this configuration in sink connector properties file?

Comment: @Atif Yes, you need to add the above lines in your connector's config file .

Comment: @ Giorgos, i have added in connect-avro-standalone.properties file but no luck.

Comment: `connect-avro-standalone.properties` is not the connector's configuration file but the Kafka connect configuration. You need to add the transformations in the config file of your connector.

Comment: Thanks It works but what will be the value of $Value this field?

Comment: @Atif You don't have to change anything; `$Value` simply denotes that this transformation should take place on the value (as opposed to `$Key`)